# android actionbar searchview icon change

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I need to know how can I change actionbar searchview icon when click on it? I'm currently using "Theme.Holo.Light" and I don't want to change this theme anymore. Is there anyway can change SearchView icon in ActionBar when click on it?

Comment: its easy to change the searchview icon, when we use custom actionbar..

Comment: custom actionbar means?

Comment: Do you want to change the icon when the search view gets expanded?

Comment: while using default actionbar sherlock library.. its bit to difficult to change the icon,, custom action bar, that time, we will create seperate layout for that searchview.. that time, its easy to change icon and whatever..

Comment: I'm not using sherlock. I'm using built-in android library.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible to do.
What you should do is create custom layout for the search menu option let say searchLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/img_search"
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

now use this layout in your menu option.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
        android:id="@+id/menuSearch"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/searchLayout"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="search"/>

</menu>
```

now you just have to get the view from the menu option :

```
    @Override
        public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu( Menu menu )
        {
          final MenuItem item = menu.findItem( R.id.menuSearch );

         LinearLayout layoutSearchView = (LinearLayout) item.getActionView();

         ImageView img = (ImageView) layoutSearchView.findViewById( R.id. img_search);

       // now you have your image of search . on click you can change the image using set onclick listener of image or do what ever you want with the layout.

       img.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick( View v )
                    {
                        // change your image
                    }
                } );
    }
```

sorry for any typo.
Hope this will help.

Note : I am doing change image code in `onPrepareOptionsMenu` in this snippet but I suggest to create a method and  pass the menu item from onPrepareOptionsMenu and do the task in that method.

Comment: Sorry.. It doesn't work. It still appear "grey" search button

Comment: have you get the layoutSearchView? please debug and check

Comment: i post the code how you can get the view on  onPrepareOptionsMenu . have you check that?

Comment: What I want is I want to get like SearchView. Regarding your code, only Image View appear. TextView is missing.

Comment: you can put textview also in that layout that's not a big deal.

Comment: it is custom layout you can put as many control as you wish in it.

Comment: see my edited answer you will see the click listner where you can change the image